# Is there a stunnel / other SSL tunnel equivalent of "ssh -D"?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssl, socks5, stunnel

I am trying to find a way to set up an SSL tunnel and use a SOCKS proxy in the same matter that I am using `ssh -D <port>`.
Is there any equivalent of doing so using stunnnel?
I am using a linux machine.
Thanks